# Windows 11 - explorer.exe randomly crashing when shift right-clicking on taskbar

Tags: windows-explorer, crash, taskbar, windows-11-v22h2

If I shift+right click (re-enabled functionality via registry) an icon in my taskbar, explorer.exe randomly crashes and restarts, killing all my open explorer-windows which is kinda annoying. After that one crash, shift+right click produces no further crashes.

First guess was to blame any of the non-MS context menu-entries but as I only have 5 such listed in ShellExView (7Zip, Notepad++ and 3 from Nvidia) that doesn't seem to be the case.
Immediately after a restart shift+right click also works fine further disproving the theory.

Explorer.exe .dmp-file content:

```
ExceptionAddress: 00007ff9016bc737 (Windows_UI_Xaml!CXcpDispatcher::CheckReentrancy+0x00000000002e22d1)
   ExceptionCode: c000027b
  ExceptionFlags: 00000001
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 0000000028d425c0
   Parameter[1]: 0000000000000001
```

Any help to avoid further crashes would be appreciated.

Comment: What was the registry modification that you did? Does this happen when you boot in Safe mode?

Comment: @harrymc

Was this command:
`reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{86ca1aa0-34aa-4e8b-a509-50c905bae2a2}\InprocServer32" /f /ve`


Haven't tried using safe mode for so long as it happens randomly after a while.
For example, I just rebooted my PC 2 hours ago and I tried to provoke the crash with no success.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to hack Windows 11 in order to
[Get Back Classic (Full) Context Menu in Windows 11](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/get-classic-full-context-menu-windows-11/).

Try to undo the modification with this command :

```
reg delete HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{86ca1aa0-34aa-4e8b-a509-50c905bae2a2} /f
```

and reboot. If this solves the problem, then it is directly caused
by this registry modification.

Try a more explicit command:

```
reg add HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{86ca1aa0-34aa-4e8b-a509-50c905bae2a2}\InprocServer32 /ve /d "" /f`
```

If this also does not work, use the undo command to return to a stable
version. The conclusion then would be that this hack no longer works
on the latest Windows 11.